# Can you go up and down a range in one for loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, kotlin

Is there some way to do the following in one for loop?

```
fun main() {
    val x = 6
    for (i in 1..x){
        println(i)
    }
    for(i in x-1 downTo 1){
        println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For Loop with Multivariable in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53339952/for-loop-with-multivariable-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
for (i in (1..x) + (x-1 downTo 1)) {
    println(i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could combine them in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this,

```
val x = 6
for (i in 1..x){
    println(i)
    println(x - i + 1)
}
```